# How to implement a grapher in C#

Tags: c#, math, graphics, gdi+, calculator

So I'm writing a graphing calculator. So far I have a semi-functional grapher, however, I'm having a hard time getting a good balance between accurate graphs and smooth looking curves.

The current implementation (semi-pseudo-code) looks something like this:

```
for (float i = GraphXMin; i <= GraphXMax; i++)
{
    PointF P = new PointF(i, EvaluateFunction(Function, i)
    ListOfPoints.Add(P)
}
Graphics.DrawCurve(ListOfPoints)
```

The problem with this is since it only adds a point at every integer value, graphs end up distorted when their turning points don't fall on integers (e.g. *sin(x)^2*).

[image]

I tried incrementing *i* by something smaller (like 0.1), which works, but the graph looks very rough.

[image]

I am using C# and GDI+. I have SmoothingMethod set to AntiAlias, so that's not the problem, as you can see from the first graph. Is there some sort of issue with drawing curves with a lot of points? Should the points perhaps be positioned exactly on pixels?

I'm sure some of you have worked on something very similar before, so any suggestions? While you're at it, do you have any suggestions for graphing functions with asymptotes? e.g. 1/x^2

P.S. I'm not looking for a library that does all this - I want to write it myself.

Comment: what you mean by "the graph looks very rough"? increasing the number of points is the way to go, to make it look more smooth. And making the X-steps smaller (1 -> 0.1) *does* increase them.

Comment: Also I dont know, what you mean with "suggestions for graphing functions with asymptotes". What you expect? How are they handles differently to other graphs? They are not.

Comment: I've edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I fixed the problem. Somewhere in the drawing process I was using int rather than float.

Answer (score 2):

When rendering a graph you are always making rounding errors because a bitmap is discrete and the graph isn't.

There several ways of coping:

1. use anti-aliasing; it's just making the graph look smoother.
2. use a non-lineair interpolation. Drawing from point a to b using a lineair interpolation causes angles. Calculate the slope of the graph (not of the line segment!) in each point and feed the slope to the interpolation method (bicubic or bezier curve)

Using vector APIs such as WPF or Silverlight might make things easier to implement.

Taking care of asymptotes is pretty hard. First you have to find them and then skip the value so you can make the 'hole' in the graph.